# Python not catching error from SSL certificate mismatch

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to execute a block of code which throws the below error because of client and server certificate mismatch. But I am not able to catch this from python using any form of exceptions.

> E0911 11:26:53.861000000  8124
>   src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.c:921] Handshake failed with fatal
>   error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:0400006b:RSA
>   routines:OPENSSL_internal:BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_01.

Any idea how can I catch this exception in python?

```
try: 
    h = gnmiXT(NEIp,grpcPort,NEUser,NEPass,".*")
    h.Subscribe_maxSessions(orig_stdout, timeout=10) 
except Exception as e: 
    print str(e) 
except SSLError as e: 
    print str(e)
```

Comment: show your code, what you have done yet

Comment: try:
  h = gnmiXT(NEIp,grpcPort,NEUser,NEPass,".*")
        h.Subscribe_maxSessions(orig_stdout, timeout=10)
    except Exception as e:
  print str(e)
    except SSLError as e:
        print str(e)

Comment: sorry, i am not able to format the code. I have tried other exception forms also but to no avail.

Comment: add your custom exception above `Exception` .By default `Exception` caught all the `raise`